# Invoke-sqlcmd unexpected behaviour

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell, bcp

I am using invoke-sqlcmd to bcp out a file.
All appears to be fins and dandy, except when I try to delete the file before creating it.
It then takes a random time before the file is available.
Any ideas why ?

Faulty Code (do replace $dir and $sql_srv with your own values, of course)

```
$dir = "\\srv-ocmr\d$\temp\" 
$sql_srv = "srv-ocmr\rec1ocm" 
if (test-path $($dir+"*.dat")) {remove-item $($dir+"*.dat") } # culprit line 
$str = $("bcp sysobjects out " + $dir + "so.dat -S" + $sql_srv + " -T -N " ) 
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sql_srv  -Query "exec xp_cmdshell '$str' " -Database    master -Verbose 
while (-not (test-path $($dir+"*.dat"))) { 
    sleep -Seconds 1 
    test-path $($dir+"*.dat")
    }
```

Remove the culprit line, and voila, everything works as a charm:

```
$dir = "\\srv-ocmr\d$\temp\" 
$sql_srv = "srv-ocmr\rec1ocm" 
$str = $("bcp sysobjects out " + $dir + "so.dat -S" + $sql_srv + " -T -N " ) 
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sql_srv  -Query "exec xp_cmdshell '$str' " -Database    master -Verbose 
while (-not (test-path $($dir+"*.dat"))) { 
    sleep -Seconds 1 
    test-path $($dir+"*.dat")
    }
```

Replacing remove-item by cmd /c del doesn't change anything, the same with using a local dir instead of a UNC.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. How long does it take before file is available?

Comment: Why are you running PowerShell to instruct SQL Server to use `xp_cmdshell` to execute a shell command? Why not just run your script via remoting on the server executing `bcp` directly from within PowerShell?

Comment: Arya: it takes  random time between 4 and 15 seconds before the test-path evaluates to true.

Comment: Alroc: I posted a simplified version here, the  original is more complex, the script is interrogating merge replication tables and dynamically generates SQL statements with filters to bcp out data checksums on about 150 tables. The result is then exported into BCP native format and processed further.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough in my question, I DO have a workaround, I delete the files in a xp_cmdshell again (does it show I'm a DBA :)) I do everything in SQL :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path:$dir -Filter:'*.dat' | Remove-item -Force
```

I'm suspecting oddness happening with `Test-Path` and wildcards. With the command I posted, it will use the pipeline. If get-childitem finds no files, remove-item will just silently do nothing. If files are found, Remove-Item will try to remove them with extreme prejudice.